# How to put an if statement in a php mailer

Tags: php, email, if-statement, phpmailer

I am attempting to put an if/else statement in the body of a php mailer email. The reason I am doing this is so that I don't have to create multiple `$mail->Body` togs based on the variable `$rsvp_answer`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong and how I can get this to work correctly?

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = '
            <head>
            <style>
            #nameSec {
                margin: 0 auto 50px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .fancyFontTitle {
                font-size: 5rem;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                color: #333;
                font-family: cursive;
            }
            #weddingDate, .title {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
            .title {
                margin: 0px auto 50px auto;
                text-align: center;
                color: #2E393F;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="header-background" style="background:#C8DBD9;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div id="email-header" style="width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;display:block;padding:20px 0;">
                        <div id="nameSec">
                            <span class="fancyFontTitle"></span><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="email-link" style="width:100%;padding:15px;height:auto;background:#EBEBEB;position:relative;">
                        <div id="email-link-container" style="width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;text-align:left;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width:600px; font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;">\
            '
            if ($rsvp_answer == 'Yes') { '
                            <p>' . $rsvp_name . '</p>
                            <p>' . $rsvp_email . '</p>
                            <p>Will the guest be attending: ' . $rsvp_answer . '</p>
                            <p>Will they bring a guest: ' . $rsvp_guest_answer . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 1: ' . $guest1 . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 2: ' . $guest2 . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 3: ' . $guest3 . '</p>
            ' else {
                '           <p>Sorry you cant attend. </p>
            }               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        ';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Proposal Request Sent';
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message1 could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
```

Comment: The world doesn't work like this. You cannot use an if-else inside a string. There are rules.

Comment: doing this is too messy for that much content... `$mystring = ' start ' . ( $condition == true ? ' when true ' : ' whenfalse' ) . ' end ';` Just build up your string piece by piece using the `$mystring .= 'add this to mystring';` notation

Comment: @Scuzzy Could you show me an example of this? I've never used this notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a mail body with condition then first create the entire string and then assign it to  $mail->Body .
example

```
$str='Some String'; 
if(conditionTrue){
$str.='Concatinate onr part';
}else{
$str.='Concatinate another part';
}
//continue this way
$mail->Body=$str;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate the body sting based on the if\else like so:

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = '
            <head>
            <style>
            #nameSec {
                margin: 0 auto 50px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .fancyFontTitle {
                font-size: 5rem;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                color: #333;
                font-family: cursive;
            }
            #weddingDate, .title {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
            .title {
                margin: 0px auto 50px auto;
                text-align: center;
                color: #2E393F;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="header-background" style="background:#C8DBD9;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div id="email-header" style="width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;display:block;padding:20px 0;">
                        <div id="nameSec">
                            <span class="fancyFontTitle"></span><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="email-link" style="width:100%;padding:15px;height:auto;background:#EBEBEB;position:relative;">
                        <div id="email-link-container" style="width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;text-align:left;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width:600px; font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;">';

            if ($rsvp_answer == 'Yes') { $mail->Body.='
                            <p>' . $rsvp_name . '</p>
                            <p>' . $rsvp_email . '</p>
                            <p>Will the guest be attending: ' . $rsvp_answer . '</p>
                            <p>Will they bring a guest: ' . $rsvp_guest_answer . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 1: ' . $guest1 . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 2: ' . $guest2 . '</p>
                            <p>Guest 3: ' . $guest3 . '</p>';
             }else {
                $mail->Body.='<p>Sorry you cant attend. </p>';
            }               
                $mail->Body.='         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        ';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Proposal Request Sent';
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message1 could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
```

Comment: For some reason, this makes the email send twice.

Comment: I found it. I pasted the send function twice. Thank you. Last question about this. If I wanted to put an if statement in this part, `<p>Will the guest be attending: ' . $rsvp_answer . '</p>` do I have to concatentate the `$mail->Body.-` again?